# Configure keep alive to keep connection alive all the time

Tags: spring-integration

I have a tcp client-server application where the client opens a connection which is for single use and disconnects after configured time. How can I configure it keep the connection alive all the time, reconnect on closed connection and ensure multiple clients connections are open to the server.

**Client config:**

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="client"
    type="client"
    host="${server.TCP.host}"
    port="${server.TCP.port}"
    single-use="true"
    so-timeout="${client.TCP.socketTimeOut}" />

<int-ip:tcp-outbound-gateway id="outGateway"
    request-channel="bytesOut"
    reply-channel="bytesIn"
    connection-factory="client"
    request-timeout="${client.TCP.requestTimeOut}"
    reply-timeout="${client.TCP.replyTimeout}" />
```

**Server config:**

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="tcpServerConnFactory"
    type="server" 
    port="${service.tcp.port}" 
    using-nio="true"
    single-use="false" 
    so-timeout="${service.tcp.socketTimeout}"
    task-executor="taskExecutor"/>

<int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway 
    id="tcpInboundGateway" 
    connection-factory="tcpServerConnFactory" 
    request-channel="bytesInChannel"
    reply-channel="bytesOutChannel"
    error-channel="errorChannel" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Single use on the client side means exactly that - each socket is used for one request/reply then closed.

When `single-use="false"`, one shared connection is used for all requests/replies - and each caller blocks waiting for the socket.

You can use a 'CachingClientConnectionFactory` to maintain a pool of permanent connections - see [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/ip.html#caching-cf).

> As noted above, TCP sockets can be single-use (one request/response) or shared. Shared sockets do not perform well with outbound gateways, in high-volume environments, because the socket can only process one request/response at a time.
>
> To improve performance, users could use collaborating channel adapters instead of gateways, but that requires application-level message correlation. See Section 31.8, “TCP Message Correlation” for more information.
>
> Spring Integration 2.2 introduced a caching client connection factory, where a pool of shared sockets is used, allowing a gateway to process multiple concurrent requests with a pool of shared connections.

The upcoming 5.0 release - currently at milestone 7 (5.0.0.M7). Has a [Thread Affinity Connection Factory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.0.M7/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-affinity-cf) which keeps a connection open per calling thread.

Comment: Removing so-timeout on both client and server and setting single-use=false on client side achieved what I was looking for. However if the server restarts how can I guarantee that the client would connect automatically?

Comment: A new connection is automatically created when sending the next message if the current connection is closed.

Comment: Thanks @Gary for the valuable suggestion.